# timeIntervalSinceDate not returning correct answer objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm trying to get `timeIntervalSinceDate` to send a log in secs of how much time has elapsed since a previous date but it isn't working. I set it for 1 minute in the future each time I test it but I not get logs that correspond like the latest log was this: `2015-09-22 16:30:04.469 Wakey Wakey[49785:7077539] Seconds nan 2015-09-22 16:30:04.470`. This is the code:

```
NSString *dateTimeString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: dateTimePicker.date ];
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd:MM:YYYY:ss:mm:hh"];
NSDate *dateTimeSeconds = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateTimeSeconds = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateTimeString];
NSTimeInterval secs = [currentTime timeIntervalSinceDate:dateTimeSeconds];
NSLog(@"Seconds %g", secs);
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Make your date format actually match the format of your date string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bother with NSDateFormatter. Try

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateTimePicker.date];

NSLog(@"seconds %.f", seconds);
```

Also use %.f instead of %g on the NSLog

Comment: why is it %f instead of %g

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
NSDate* date1 = someDate;
 NSDate* date2 = someOtherDate;
 NSTimeInterval distanceBetweenDates = [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate:date2];
 double secondsInAnHour = 3600;
 NSInteger hoursBetweenDates = distanceBetweenDates / secondsInAnHour;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try with below date format

```
kTimeStampFormat @"dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

Use UTC format for consistency

Comment: This does not match the string at all.